# PrimeFaces status bar is static rather than animated

Tags: jsf, animation, jsf-2, primefaces

I have been following the example on the PrimeFaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf)

What I am trying to do is display a static bar of set value (10%) but have the animated effect of the animated bar. I have tried to combine both of them to get the static value I need but the effect I want is still only completely static

```
<p:progressBar value="10" 
               labelTemplate="{value}%" 
               ajax="true" 
               styleClass="animated"> 
</p:progressBar>
```

That is my code. How can I achieve the animated look on a set value?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of obtaining animated *p:progressBar*. One is **client** side animation, where you handle it from JavaScript (perfect for simple and usually predefined animation). The other is **ajax**-based, where current value is calculated in server-side bean and updated periodically  (it can work as in showcase example, but it would be even more suitable to present progress of complex and rather asynchronous operations). Either way, any animated behaviour excludes **static** nature.

The sample of code you showed declares the progress bar with some static value - but it doesn't handle its animation. If you need animation that stops on some value, the good approach would be to handle it from JavaScript. Code should be very similar to that in showcase example but you would need to tamper with values of step size, interval and animation end condition. If you want to get your progress bar animated automatically you can combine it with HTML events. The details of implementation will strongly depend on the specific behaviour you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ppawel, the only thing I would add is that if you want the animation to run as soon as you load the page, you could use *`<body onload="animationFunction()">`* of course you need to write *animationFunction()* in javascript